# Why does Rust "From" trait implementation give lifetime error, but custom trait does not?

Tags: rust, lifetime

The following code can work when I use a custom trait.  But I don't understand why it fails when trying to use the builtin "From" trait.

```
struct A {
    x: isize,
}

enum SimpleEnum {
    A(A),
    B(u8),
}

trait FromCustom {
    fn from_custom(value: &SimpleEnum) -> &A;
}

impl FromCustom for &SimpleEnum {
    fn from_custom(value: &SimpleEnum) -> &A {
        if let SimpleEnum::A(value) = value {
            value // NO error
        } else {
            panic!();
        }
    }
}

impl From<&SimpleEnum> for &A {
    fn from(value: &SimpleEnum) -> Self {
        if let SimpleEnum::A(value) = value {
            value // error
        } else {
            panic!();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> rust_pst_bin/src/main.rs:55:13
   |
53 |     fn from(value: &SimpleEnum) -> Self {
   |                    -               ---- return type is &'2 A
   |                    |
   |                    let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
54 |         if let SimpleEnum::A(value) = value {
55 |             value // error
   |             ^^^^^ associated function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'2` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference has to do with inferred lifetimes.

Your custom trait has references in both the parameter and return type; due to [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html), your trait is equivalent to the following:

```
trait FromCustom {
    fn from_custom<'a>(value: &'a SimpleEnum) -> &'a A;
}
```

So by the signature alone, the return type is bound to the lifetime of the parameter.

In contrast, the `From` trait is written as such:

```
pub trait From<T>: Sized {
    fn from(value: T) -> Self;
}
```

There is no implicit linking of lifetimes between `T` and `Self` since there are no obvious lifetimes in use. And thus when you write your implementation, the `&SimpleEnum` and `&A` have *distinct* lifetimes, as if written like so:

```
impl<'a, 'b> From<&'b SimpleEnum> for &'a A {
    fn from(value: &'b SimpleEnum) -> Self {
        if let SimpleEnum::A(value) = value {
            value // error
        } else {
            panic!();
        }
    }
}
```

What is inferred is that a `&SimpleEnum` of *any* lifetime can be used to create a `&A` with *any* lifetime, which is untrue. You instead need to communicate that a `&SimpleEnum` with a particular lifetime can be used to create a `&A` with that lifetime. You can do that by linking the lifetimes together yourself:

```
impl<'a> From<&'a SimpleEnum> for &'a A {
    fn from(value: &'a SimpleEnum) -> Self {
        if let SimpleEnum::A(value) = value {
            value
        } else {
            panic!();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not provide any lifetimes to your `From<&SimpleEnum>` impl, the compiler assigns to `&SimpleEnum` (and hence the parameter `value`) a *different* lifetime than the lifetime of `Self` (or `&A`). Desugared, the `impl` would be as follows:

```
impl<'a, 'b> From<&'a SimpleEnum> for &'b A {
    fn from(value: &'a SimpleEnum) -> Self {
        if let SimpleEnum::A(value) = value {
            value
        } else {
            panic!();
        }
    }
}
```

This would not work as `Self` has a different lifetime `'b` compared to `value`'s lifetime `'a`. You have to explicitly tell the compiler that the two lifetimes are the same:

```
impl<'a> From<&'a SimpleEnum> for &'a A {
    fn from(value: &'a SimpleEnum) -> Self {
        if let SimpleEnum::A(value) = value {
            value
        } else {
            panic!();
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5cae574c8e47a55d2079511b5712974)

Comment: @kmdreko you are correct; I didn't quite think my answer through. I have edited it to be more accurate.